# Wordpress user registration mail error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed WordPress 4.2.2 on XAMPP and configured it to multi-site and then installed `buddy-press` on WordPress. Now,the network has only one user that's me(super admin).
Now when I tried to register an user it said that a mail is sent to user email but email was not received.I googled the problem and then followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GsHbf4Gitw) and installed `wp-mail-smtp` plugin but still while I am sending a test mail I am receiving an error. I have struggling long. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

wp-mail-smtp can be tricky to setup and you could also be blocked by your internet provider (if you don't have a business internet line some ports are most likely blocked)

I would suggest in looking at something like http://postmarkapp.com/ and the WordPress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/postmark-approved-wordpress-plugin/ It's a lot easier to setup.